# How can I concatenate the results of two cursors with one of each cursor value?

Tags: for-loop, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to put two values together as one with two cursors. I need to put a code with a plan, for each code and each plan.

```
declare
external_code varchar2(100);
internal_code varchar2(100);
internal_group varchar2(100);

cursor codes is
select code
from codes_table
where code in ('371', '373', '376', '378', '391', '393', '396', '398');

cursor plan_codes is
select distinct plan
from plans_table
where code = '378'; --This will grab all the plans that I need.

begin
for code1 in codes loop
    external_code := code1.code;
    for plans in plan_codes loop
    external_code := external_code || ' ' || plans.plan;
    dbms_output.put_line(external_code);
    end loop;
end loop;
end;
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
371 FB
371 FC
371 FD
371 FF
371 FG
373 FB
373 FC
373 FD
373 FF
373 FG
```

etc etc and through the list. The trouble I'm running in to (which is probably something simple) is the inner loop is running wild (like it should) and appending each of the plans on one line like this:

```
371 FB
371 FB FC
371 FB FC FD
371 FB FC FD FF
```

I have toyed with `continues` and `exits` but I can't seem to get it quite right.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate an explanation for a downvote. I can't make it better if you don't tell me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the inner for loop you are using `external_code := external_code || ' ' || plan.plans`

So, next time when the inner loop runs the external_code  will be  having the  concatenated value.

Instead try using another variable like for example `external_code1 := external_code || ' ' || plan.plans`

Comment: Thanks so much. That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix.  The commented out line was building it out horizontally by changing the `external_code` variable. Instead, Just print it out for each code, for each plan in the `DBMS_OUTPUT` call. Oh I added the order by's in the queries so values come out nice and orderly too:

```
declare
  external_code varchar2(100);
  internal_code varchar2(100);
  internal_group varchar2(100);

  cursor codes is
  select code
  from CODES_TABLE
  where code in ('371', '373', '376', '378', '391', '393', '396', '398')
  order by code;

  cursor plan_codes is
  select distinct plan
  from plans_table
  where code = '378'
  order by plan; --This will grab all the plans that I need.

begin
  for code1 in codes loop
    external_code := code1.code;
    for plans in plan_codes loop
      --external_code := external_code || ' ' || plans.plan;
      dbms_output.put_line(external_code|| ' ' || plans.plan);
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

EDIT:  For the fun of it you can select the data via a query too and eliminate the overhead of those variables and cursors, etc unless you need them for other purposes not mentioned in the original post:

```
SQL> SELECT C.CODE, PLAN
  2  FROM CODES_TABLE C CROSS JOIN PLANS_TABLE P
  3  WHERE     (C.CODE IN ('371',
  4                        '373',
  5                        '376',
  6                        '378',
  7                        '391',
  8                        '393',
  9                        '396',
 10                        '398'))
 11  AND (P.CODE = '378')
 12  ORDER BY C.CODE, PLAN;

CODE       PLAN
---------- -----
371        FB
371        FC
371        FD
371        FF
371        FG
373        FB
373        FC
373        FD
373        FF
373        FG
...
```

Comment: Well kudos to you for being thorough! Nicely done. As for the overhead, I am going to be inserting this data, along with other information, into a table. Pretty sure I'm going to need the overhead :) Luckily it's a one time shot.